# Cube animation in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, animation

I've used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614339/angularjs-with-ng-animate-ng-view-how-to-make-a-3d-cube-rotation-effect) to create a cube control.

[This is](http://jsfiddle.net/bnyJ6/137/) what i've got so far.

I'm using `ng-if` and `ng-include` to trigger the animation

```
<div ng-repeat='view in views' class='cube container'>
    <div ng-if='view.name == selected' " + 
            ng-include='view.template' " + 
            ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter',
                            leave: 'animate-leave'}"> 
    </div>
</div>
```

I've got two questions

1. When moving from pane 1 to pane 3 it should go through pane 2. I made a loop that first changes the selected pane to #2 and then to #3 but the animation is going straight to #3. is there a way to "wait" till the transition to #2 complete before moving to #3 ?
2. I'm having trouble making the cube control fixed in size. If you'll add in the example above another `cube-viewer` you'll see that they overlap.

I'm aiming at a CSS only solution (no key frame nor java script / jquery animations)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. use goTOPrev(), goTONext() method inside goTo() method.

   Using $timeout, loop through the views until it reaches the right target, i.e. 500 ms.
2. remove fixed.

   style="/* position:fixed; */ display:block; width:450px; padding:0; margin:0; border:1px solid #EEE;" ...

Comment: Thanks for the response - I tried your solution for 1, its working but not a smooth as I hoped, you have any other tips for me ? about 2, it's not working. http://jsfiddle.net/bnyJ6/138/

Comment: about 2, it's working as i expected. I see two views on top and bottom separately. If you want to see those left/right, use float:left

Comment: the problem is that during the animation the outer frame is shrinking causing the two cubes to overlap.

Comment: Because you did not set height, so it is auto. Adding this "height:470px;" won't make it collape with animation.

Comment: About #1, I don't know what you want. It's totally up to you. You can increase timeout, or reorganize timeout to call timeout.